# Helping with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would appreciate helping me and correcting my mistakes. :)

1- Consider the following code 

**Set the initial value of count to 12

While (NOT (count is 0))

    Write out the value of count in the output window
    Move to the next line in the output window

    Reduce count by 3

Write ‘Finished’**

Find the answer of following statement in the code above
**A.   find the condition**
The condition is: NOT(count is 0).
**B.   find the loop body**
The loop body consists of the three instructions:
Write out the value of count in the output window
    Move to the next line in the output window
    Reduce count by 3

**C.   find any instructions that are not in the loop body, and so are not repeated
There are two instructions outside the loop body:**
Set the initial value of count to 12
Write ‘Finished’

**D.   How many times will the loop body be executed?**
4 times
**E.   What will the output be?**
Finished
**F.   Which instruction in the loop body ensures that the loop is not an infinite loop?**

Reduce count by 3

Thank you in advanced..

Comment: Hi Julia.  Your question isn't clear.  Here are [some improvements](http://stacklint.aboutscript.com/17895669) that could be made.  Most importantly, what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like a homework question to me. This is allowed, but don't let others do your homework for you, instead, ask a specific question about where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and same in E ,  12....3 finished

Comment: Do you mean there is 2 outputs ? 12....3 and finished

Comment: yes :))

12
12 -> 9
9 -> 6
6 -> 3
3 -> finished

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to question E is not correct. The output should contain what is written in the while loop too.

Comment: I didn't understand you! do you mean question C ?